# Explanation on year format behaviour for PHP DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601, php-internals

Using [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) to manage date and time formats I'm in trouble dealing with "year only" dates.

**Example** : `new DateTime(2013);` give me:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-11-27 20:13:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Paris
)
```

I know that according to [PHP DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) documentation:

> Note: The "Year (and just the year)" format only works if a time
>   string has already been found -- otherwise this format is recognised
>   as HH MM.

That note is not clear for me, can I have an explanation in a clearer way of this behaviour?

Comment: Not sure what we can add to the error - if you only pass 4 digits to the constructor, it assumes you're passing HHMM. So your date is set to today, at 20:13. Where you've got an ambiguous date format like this, you should use `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: Its in your note, 2013 will become todays date with hour `20:13`, like its showing.

Comment: **if a time string has already been found** - no time string is taken to constuctor

Comment: So `$d = new DateTime('12:00 2013'); ' it works fine

Comment: Well... I was just misunderstanding this sentence.
Thank you all !

Comment: Since PHP does not accept incomplete dates anyway, I normally try to avoid relying on hidden defaults and make it obvious, as in `new DateTime("2013-01-01 00:00:00")` (and, yes, I also avoid forcing the string parser to its limits).

Comment: I would question why you need a `DateTime` instance to deal with a single integer in the first place…

Comment: @deceze I'm using the ISO 8601 specification to manage date and time in an API.  A user can filter on a year only (See **Formats** part in [W3 Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)) and that would result on a single integer...).
Wikipedia page on **ISO 8601** says : 
"Date and time values are ordered from the largest to smallest unit of time: year, month (or week), day, [...]".

I was assuming that using **DateTime** without specifying any format would work as I expected...